# Scope of ScaleTransform

Tags: vb.net, image, winforms, graphics, visual-studio-2017

Clearly, I am not correctly understanding the ScaleTransform and TranslateTransform classes correctly.  I am trying to build a new class for the display of pop-up images that will allow the user to pan and zoom, i.e. nothing too exotic - or so I thought.

I have trawled through dozens of previous posys, helpers, tutorials, etc, but cannot find the answer to my apparently fundamental misunderstanding. I can get the correct result, i.e. the centering of an image in its container (a picture box fully docked within a splitter panel) but I would like to draw the image using DrawImage with the format:

Drawimage(image, destrect as RectangleF, srcrect as RectangleF, srcunit as GraphicsUnit)

The following code works, i.e. the image is nicely centred:

```
Private Sub SetDestinationRectangle()

    With Me
        '
        '   We always centre the image, independent of
        '   whether it is taller than wide or vice versa.
        '
        SetScale()

        .GvgImageOffsetX = (CSng(.GvoPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Width) - (.GvoSourceImage.Width * .GvgImageScaleX)) / 2

        .GvgImageOffsetY = (CSng(.GvoPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Height) - (.GvoSourceImage.Height * .GvgImageScaleY)) / 2

        .GvoImageDestinationRectangle = New RectangleF(
            0,
            0,
            .GvoSourceImage.Width,
            .GvoSourceImage.Height
            )

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub SetScale()

    With Me

        .GvgImageScaleX = CSng(.GvoPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Width) / .GvoImageSourceRectangle.Width

        .GvgImageScaleY = CSng(.GvoPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Height) / .GvoImageSourceRectangle.Height
        '
        '   To preserve the aspect ratio we
        '   use the smaller scale factor.
        '
        .GvgImageScaleX = Math.Min(.GvgImageScaleX, .GvgImageScaleY)

        .GvgImageScaleY = .GvgImageScaleX

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

    With Me

        SetDestinationRectangle()

        If .GvbDrawInLowResolution Then

            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighSpeed
            e.Graphics.CompositingMode = Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighSpeed
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor

        Else

            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
            e.Graphics.CompositingMode = Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic

        End If

        e.Graphics.ResetTransform()

        e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel

        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(.GvgImageScaleX, .GvgImageScaleY, order:=Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append)

        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(.GvgImageOffsetX, .GvgImageOffsetY, order:=Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append)

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(.GvoSourceImage, .GvoImageDestinationRectangle, .GvoImageSourceRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

    End With

End Sub
```

However, what I thought I should be able to do is to make GvgImageOffsetX and GvgImageOffsetY the x and y points of GvoImageDestinationRectangle, remove the TranslateTransform and I should get a centred image, as before, given that I expected the ScaleTransform to also have a scaling effect on all points within GvoImageDestinationRectangle.  Thus, the new code would look like:

````
        With Me
            '
            '   We always centre the image, independent of
            '   whether it is taller than wide or vice versa.
            '
            SetScale()

            .GvgImageOffsetX = (CSng(.GvoPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Width) - (.GvoSourceImage.Width * .GvgImageScaleX)) / 2

            .GvgImageOffsetY = (CSng(.GvoPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Height) - (.GvoSourceImage.Height * .GvgImageScaleY)) / 2

            .GvoImageDestinationRectangle = New RectangleF(
                .GvgImageOffsetX,
                .GvgImageOffsetY,
                .GvoSourceImage.Width,
                .GvoSourceImage.Height
                )

        End With

    End Sub

    Private Sub SetScale()

        With Me

            .GvgImageScaleX = CSng(.GvoPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Width) / .GvoImageSourceRectangle.Width

            .GvgImageScaleY = CSng(.GvoPictureBox.ClientRectangle.Height) / .GvoImageSourceRectangle.Height
            '
            '   To preserve the aspect ratio we
            '   use the smaller scale factor.
            '
            .GvgImageScaleX = Math.Min(.GvgImageScaleX, .GvgImageScaleY)

            .GvgImageScaleY = .GvgImageScaleX

        End With

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

        With Me

            SetDestinationRectangle()

            If .GvbDrawInLowResolution Then

                e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighSpeed
                e.Graphics.CompositingMode = Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy
                e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighSpeed
                e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor

            Else

                e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
                e.Graphics.CompositingMode = Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy
                e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
                e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic

            End If

            e.Graphics.ResetTransform()

            e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel

            e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(.GvgImageScaleX, .GvgImageScaleY, order:=Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append)

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(.GvoSourceImage, .GvoImageDestinationRectangle, .GvoImageSourceRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        End With

```    End Sub

What have I misunderstood?  Any help would be much appreciated.
````